# Cannot find Module errors

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I am trying to run a [demo](https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos) by John Papa from PluralSight.  On running `gupl serve-dev` I am getting:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_transform.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/paulmackey/Programming/Angular/AngularIntro/JohnPapa/ng-demos/modular/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/transform.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

ILooking inside transform.js I see:

`module.exports = require("./lib/_stream_transform.js")`

There is no ./lib folder.  I assume this means "current directory lib" as opposed to "root folder lib", in either case this folder does not exist.  I originally ran `npm install` at the project root and I still had a bunch more of these errors.  I got rid of a lot of them with `npm i --save someDependencyName`.

I'm new to AngularJs so I dunno what to do.  I've seen Angular introduce a lot of breaking changes so maybe that's the issue?  Or something is wrong with my machine installs?

Comment: Is that link to demo correct? There's no mention of `serve-dev` anywhere.

Comment: @Heikki No wrong link sorry.  Updated.